# How to set value of spinbox in fuelux scheduler

Tags: javascript, scheduler, fuelux

I am using scheduler from fuelux for my project, but I found some bugs. See the live demo for example: http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/javascript.html#scheduler

If the user types in letters like 'abc' for repeat times or end after occurances, it becomes zero ('0') while I want it to be one ('1'). Also, I want the default value of end after occurances to be one.

These are two spinboxes in the scheduler, namely repeat-every and end-after, if you see fuelux.js for reference. I am wondering if I can change it so that it makes more sense for users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No default value is set for that spinbox control for the 'end after' setting. This is most likely a bug and not the intent, since you can't have end after 0 times. You can [see the code here in scheduler.js](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/master/js/scheduler.js#L78). I would recommend [submitting an issue on Github](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/new) or a pull request.

You can temporarily use the following instead:

`this.$endAfter.spinbox({ 'value': 1, 'min': 1 });`

Comment: @Internative Llama Thanks! This works. But how could I do to deal with junk inputs like 'abc' which is not numbers?